# question with space of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $C_s^N$ to be the space of bi-directional sequences f which  f[m+N] = f[m]   .
For each $f ∈ C_s^N$ , we define $∇_+ f [m] = f[m+1] – f[m]$   .      for p>1  , we define $∇_+^p = ∇_+  (∇_+^{p-1})$

1. Calculate  $∇_+^2f[m]$
2. Show that if $f ∈ C_s^N$ and exist  p∈N  which hold $∇_+^p f≡ 0$ ,   so $f≡ c$ for some constant c

Comment: Well, obviously, a function which becomes zero after differentiating a few times is a polynomial, and the only periodic polynomial is a constant.

Comment: No, you're confusing.  This symbol is not related to differentiation.   it's just new symbol - refer to definition in the question.

Comment: Yes, I got that. You've been given just the definition and supposed to deduce everything else from that. You are **not** supposed to use any previous knowledge, or even to notice that this new thing is somehow related to something you could have met before. **But it is**, and that's how.

Comment: thank you for your time and response, but again - your assumption "a function which becomes zero after differentiating a few times"  is not correct. 
I think it should be related to some rule when calculating ∇^p (f)  - like:
∇^2(f) =  f[m+2]-2f[m+1]+f[m]
∇^3(f) = ... 
then ∇^p (f) = 0   => here we should conclude it but i fail to do.

Comment: Just how is it not correct? Do you know any such sequence which is not a polynomial?

Comment: but where do you see that it "becomes zero after differentiating few times" ?  there's no differentation here at all.    it's only general operator that do:  f[m+1] - f[m]  .  Nothing here related to differentiation.

Comment: OK, let it be your way. I claim that any sequence that becomes a constant zero after applying this new operator a finite number of times is a polynomial.

Comment: OK - I dont know if I can depend on this claim, as i can't prove it :)